# Enzyme, how to simulate key press combinations? [ALT+S]

Tags: enzyme

is it possible to simulate combined ket presses in enzyme? I need to test global keyboard shortcuts. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about global shortcuts. Basically to simulate an `event` on control, the control is expected to have that kind of events. Assuming you have `Component` with, let's say, `input` and you listen for `keyDown` <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> on it, the code will be following:

```js
 describe('Component', () => {
    it('simulate shortcut', () => {
        const keyDownFunc = jest.fn();//or other mock
        const underTest = shallow(<Component onKeyDown={keyDownFunc}/>);
        underTest.find("input").simulate("keyDown", {altKey: true, key: 's'});
        expect(keyDownFunc).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```